# Setting up cloned wordpress repository on mamp

Tags: wordpress, mamp

I have cloned wordpress git repository to my htdocs directory on MAMP server locally. I have also created and imported the database to MAMP server. And have added an entry to `/etc/hosts`that looks like this now:

```
127.0.0.1 localhost
127.0.0.1 superselma.dev
```

I have restarted MAMP server and went to see the website in the browser, but all I get is the message:

> It works!

And when I do:

```
http://localhost:8888/superselma
```

I get:

> Not Found
>
> The requested URL /superselma was not found on this server.

I have configured wp-config.php file:

```
define('DB_NAME', 'superselma');

/** MySQL database username */
define('DB_USER', 'root');

/** MySQL database password */
define('DB_PASSWORD', 'root');

/** MySQL hostname */
define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');
```

This is how the vhosts file on mamp looks like:

```
#
# Virtual Hosts
#
# If you want to maintain multiple domains/hostnames on your
# machine you can setup VirtualHost containers for them. Most configurations
# use only name-based virtual hosts so the server doesn't need to worry about
# IP addresses. This is indicated by the asterisks in the directives below.
#
# Please see the documentation at
# <URL:http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/>
# for further details before you try to setup virtual hosts.
#
# You may use the command line option '-S' to verify your virtual host
# configuration.

#
# Use name-based virtual hosting.
#
NameVirtualHost *:80

#
# VirtualHost example:
# Almost any Apache directive may go into a VirtualHost container.
# The first VirtualHost section is used for all requests that do not
# match a ServerName or ServerAlias in any <VirtualHost> block.
#
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@dummy-host.example.com
    DocumentRoot "/Applications/MAMP/Library/docs/dummy-host.example.com"
    ServerName dummy-host.example.com
    ServerAlias www.dummy-host.example.com
    ErrorLog "logs/dummy-host.example.com-error_log"
    CustomLog "logs/dummy-host.example.com-access_log" common
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@dummy-host2.example.com
    DocumentRoot "/Applications/MAMP/Library/docs/dummy-host2.example.com"
    ServerName dummy-host2.example.com
    ErrorLog "logs/dummy-host2.example.com-error_log"
    CustomLog "logs/dummy-host2.example.com-access_log" common
</VirtualHost>

# Auto-VirtualHosts with .dev
<VirtualHost *:8888>
 ServerName dev
 ServerAlias *.dev
 VirtualDocumentRoot /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/%-2+
</VirtualHost>
```

My apache port is set to `8888` and document root is set to `Applications/Mamp/htdocs` where my cloned project directory is, so not sure what am I doing wrong?

Comment: A few questions:
1. what does your vhosts file look like?
2. is your wp-config.php file already configured?
3. if the wp-config file isn't configured (you should only see the example file) , did you go through the wizard?

Comment: I will edit the question with the examples of the wp-config file and vhosts file. There was no wizard.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would setup my environment. I assume you want the Wordpress clone to run under the URL superselma.dev.

I also assume that you enabled virtual hosts in your htdocs.conf file.

1. Delete the wp-config.php you just created leaving only the example one they provide. Once you setup your web server your first call to superselma.dev will bring up a wizard that will ask you all the questions required in human readable format.
2. Configure a virtual host specifically for your wordpress site.

   `<VirtualHost *:80> 
       ServerAdmin webmaster@dummy-host.example.com 
       DocumentRoot "Insert path to Wordpress root here. " 
       ServerName superselma.dev

       ServerAlias superselma.dev 
       ErrorLog "logs/dummy-host.example.com-error_log" 
       CustomLog "logs/dummy-host.example.com-access_log" 
       common 
   </VirtualHost>`
3. Restart your apache service.
4. Go to http://superselma.dev in your browser.

If done right you will see a wordpress installation wizard that will ask you for your database details. Be sure that your MySQL environment is running in xamp beforehand and that you have an empty for Wordpress to do its thing (create database worpress_sandbox).

Comment: I have tried your suggestion but on restarting apache server I get an error: `Apache couldn't be started. Please check your MAMP installation and configuration.` And I haven't done anything in the htdocs.conf file, not sure what I need to do there?

Answer (score 0):

The answer was as simple as just adding :8888 after the url `superselma.dev:8888` and it worked then.